# Policy based alignment gives object unneeded extra size

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, alignment

I made a templated struct called AlignmentPolicy:

```
template<int range> 
struct AlignmentPolicy;

template<> 
struct __declspec(align(1)) AlignmentPolicy<1> { };

template<>
struct __declspec(align(2)) AlignmentPolicy<2> { };

template<>
struct __declspec(align(4)) AlignmentPolicy<4> { };

template<>
struct __declspec(align(8)) AlignmentPolicy<8> { };

template<>
struct __declspec(align(16)) AlignmentPolicy<16> { };

template<>
struct __declspec(align(32)) AlignmentPolicy<32> { };
```

And when I want a struct 16-byte aligned I just do this:

```
struct MyContainer : public AlignmentPolicy<16>
{
//... insides
};
```

However when I test my classes with sizeof() they end up being bigger than expected.For instance:

```
struct float2 : public AlignmentPolicy<16>
{
   float x;
   float y;
};
```

With 2 floats = 4 byte each.When aligned to 16, it should become 16 bytes, no?However sizeof tells me float2 is 32 bytes...I get similar behavior in all my structs that inherit AlignmentPolicy<>.Is there a way around this or must I just use __declspec(align(16)) instead?

Comment: `__declspec(align())` is no standard, so the standard cannot be used in any arguments here.

Comment: Aren't you asking that each member be aligned on 16 byte boundaries (which with two members would explain the 32 byte overall size)?

Comment: when I use it on a class with a __m128(16 bytes by default) member for instance, it also makes it 32 bytes, but when I comment out the inheritance and use __declspec(align(16)), the class remains 16 bytes